# How to wait for completion of asynchronous function c# winrt

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have code which gets the photo from a web camera. I need to write a mechanism that would be expected to complete this process. How do I do this? I have the following code:

```
ImageEncodingProperties imageProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
var memStream3 = new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
var mediaCaptureMgr1 = new MediaCapture();
await mediaCaptureMgr1.InitializeAsync();
mediaCaptureMgr1.SetPreviewMirroring(true);
await mediaCaptureMgr1.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imageProperties, memStream3);
await memStream3.FlushAsync();
memStream3.Seek(0);
WriteableBitmap wb1 = new WriteableBitmap(320, 240);
wb1.SetSource(memStream3);
//1
while (true)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
    //if CapturePhotoToStreamAsync finished? OR memStream3 not null?
    //break;
}
//2
```

If I start to do anything with wb1 at //1, I will not work because wb1 = null. If I start doing it at //2 the wb1! = null because I waited until all the async function are completed.

Comment: Do you want to replace the `while`-loop?

Comment: I don't see why you have the `while` loop in there at all. I also don't understand what you are asking. Please be more specific here...

Comment: When you await the `CapturePhotoToStreamAsync` method, the method already finished in the followed code line. That's the point of using await.

Comment: I specified in the first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `wb1.SetSource(memStream3);` you should call `await wb1.SetSourceAsync(memStream3);` and all should be good. Otherwise you could set `var wb1 = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);` and wait until `wb1.PixelWidth` grows bigger than 1 when `SetSource` is done, but this method with `Task.Delay` polling is suboptimal.